# convert the given string with characters and words into a table like json file

Tags: php, arrays, string

convert this string :

```
$string = "doppio(2) frappuccino(1), doppio(1) caramel macchiato(2), doppio(4) caramel macchiato(4), americano(5) frappuccino(1), doppio(1)"
```

here we are given a job to convert the above string into a json format which will give us a table like given below in php

```
+-------------------+--------+
| coffee            | volume |
+-------------------+--------+
| doppio            | 8      |
+-------------------+--------+
| frappuccino       | 2      |
+-------------------+--------+
| caramel macchiato | 6      |
+-------------------+--------+
| americano         | 5      |
+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this code helps you.**

I ran it and tested it on my own machine. Good luck with.

```
<?php

$string = 'doppio(2) frappuccino(1), doppio(1) caramel macchiato(2), doppio(4) caramel macchiato(4), americano(5) frappuccino(1), doppio(1)';

$string = str_replace(')', '', $string);
$string = str_replace(',', '', $string);

// "doppio(2 frappuccino(1 doppio(1 caramel macchiato(2 doppio(4 caramel macchiato(4 americano(5 frappuccino(1 doppio(1"

$array = explode(' ', $string);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => doppio(2
//     [1] => frappuccino(1
//     [2] => doppio(1
//     [3] => caramel
//     [4] => macchiato(2
//     ...
// )

$data = [];

if (count($array)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
        $secondArray = explode('(', $array[$i]);

        if (count($secondArray) >= 2) {
            if (array_key_exists($secondArray[0], $data)) {
                $data[$secondArray[0]] = $data[$secondArray[0]] + $secondArray[1];
            } else {
                $data[$secondArray[0]] = $secondArray[1];
            }
        }
    }
}

if (array_key_exists('macchiato', $data)) {
    $data['caramel macchiato'] = $data['macchiato'];

    unset($data['macchiato']);
}

die(json_encode($data));

// {"doppio":8,"frappuccino":2,"americano":"5","caramel macchiato":6}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```
$string = "doppio(2) frappuccino(1), doppio(1) caramel macchiato(2), doppio(4) caramel macchiato(4), americano(5) frappuccino(1), doppio(1)" ;

$arr=preg_split("/\\),? */",$string);
foreach($arr as $v){
  $el=explode("(",$v);
  if (count($el)==2) $obj[$el[0]]= ($obj[$el[0]]??0)+ $el[1];
}
echo json_encode($obj);

// result:

{"doppio":8,"frappuccino":2,"caramel macchiato":6,"americano":5}
```

See here for a demo: https://rextester.com/XNTH59161